# Error when running unit tests in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

If I try and run unit tests in eclipse using a predefined unit test configuration, I get the following error:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'atf'.
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project cannot be cast to               
org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder
```

I am running Eclipse Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1), I have only seen the problem with this release of Eclipse, older releases were fine...

Comment: did you manage to solve the same?